# Concatenating SumIfs in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to get this segment of code to execute. This is a simplified version of the code. I've included the relevant code. I'm trying to concatenate strings and named ranges into a SumIfs formula, but I get error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error." I have a working line of code above this problem section that is similar with the exception of doing a sum function, instead of sumif. Any idea how to get this code to execute? Thank you.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ara As Worksheet
Dim inv As Worksheet
Dim ARBlock As Range
Dim Invoices As Range
Dim AgedDays As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ara = wb.Sheets("AR Aging")
Set inv = wb.Sheets("Invoices")
Set ARBlock = ara.Range("a6")
Set Invoices = inv.Range("a6", inv.Range("a6").End(xlDown))
Set AgedDays = Invoices.Offset(0, 6)

'Populate A/R age buckets
For i = 6 To ARBlock.Rows.Count + 6
    With ARBlock(i - 5, 1).Offset(0, 3)
        .Value = "=SumIfs(" & Invoices.Offset(0, 4).Address & "," & _
                    Invoices.Address & "," & ARBlock(i - 5, 1).Value & "," & _
                    Invoices.Offset(0, 6).Address & ","" <= "" & &O30)"
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

The line beginning with ".value" is where I'm getting the error message. P.S.: I need the cell to contain the concatenated formula, as opposed to the output value.

UPDATE 1:

As some suggested I updated the .value line to:

```
.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=SumIfs(Invoices.Offset(0, 4).Address,Invoices.Address,ARBlock.cells(i - 5, 1).Value)"
```

I'm still getting the same error. Some auditing I've done:

Removing the "=" before "Sumifs" allows the code to run fine; pasting in the formula into the target cell as text. In this form, my output for i=1 goes to ARBlock.cells(1,1), as it should.

I also used Debug.Print to view all of the components of the formula:

```
Debug.Print ARBlock.Cells(i - 5, 1).Address
'output $A$6
Debug.Print ARBlock.Cells(i - 5, 1).Value
' output International Business Machines
Debug.Print Invoices.Offset(0, 4).Address
'output $E$6:$E$255
Debug.Print Invoices.Address
'output $A$6:$A$255
```

I suspected the issue might be that the range dimensions might have been off, but this is not the case. My next suspicion is that the output International Business Machines needs to be in " " for the formula to read it correctly. I hardcoded in

```
""International Business Machines""
```

to see if this would fix the formula, but I keep getting the same error once I add the "=" back in. The formula syntax is correct, the dimensions are the same between the sum range and criteria range. Anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: My guess is "ARBlock(i - 5, 1).Value" ,  the actual cell you references is a index <=0 ?

Comment: When assigning a formula you should use `.Formula`, not `.Value`  There's a lot going on in that line, so try separating it out into multiple lines and see where the error really is. Try adding a "'" at the front of the formula (to have the cell treat it as text) and see if it looks correct.

Comment: If you assign the result of your formula building to a string you will be able to see if it is a valid formula.  For a start `","" <= "" & &O30)"` doesn't look right. And `ARBlock(i - 5, 1).Value` should be `ARBlock.Cells(i - 5, 1).Value`

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Updated.

Comment: @LeoPTY Just added an answer.  Threw some quotes around your "criteria" using chr(34).  If that doesn't work, you might need to put an `=` in front of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=SumIfs(Invoices.Offset(0, 4).Address,Invoices.Address,ARBlock.cells(i - 5, 1).Value)"
```

Change to:

```
.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=SumIfs(" & Invoices.Offset(0, 4).Address & ", " & Invoices.Address & ", " & chr(34) & ARBlock.Cells(i - 5, 1).Value & chr(34) & ")"
```

EDIT:  Added quotes `chr(34)` around your string!

Answer (score -1):

Your `ARBlock(i - 5, 1).Value` most likely is an empty cell, which messes the `SUMIFS` formula as it builds it with to consecutive commas